# Find longest subsequence without NaN values in set of series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello I'm trying to figure out a method that finds the longest common continuous subsequence (in this case time interval) without any missing (Nan) values from a set of sequences. This is a example dataframe.

```
   time  s_1  s_2  s_3
0  1     2    2    Nan
1  2     3    Nan  Nan
2  3     3    2    2
3  4     5    3    10
4  5     8    4    3
5  6     Nan  Nan  7
6  7     5    2    Nan
7  8     Nan  3    Nan
```

For this small example the "best" time interval would be from 3-5 or index 2-4. The real dataframe is way bigger and contains more series. Is it possible to find an efficient solution to this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dropna` first , then we using `cumsum` with `diff` to build a key for distinguish different group by it is continue or not (different by 1 )

```
s=df.dropna()
idx=s.time.groupby(s.time.diff().ne(1).cumsum()).transform('count')
idx
0    1
2    3
3    3
4    3
Name: time, dtype: int64
yourmax=s[idx==idx.max()]
yourmax
   time  s_1  s_2   s_3
2     3  3.0  2.0   2.0
3     4  5.0  3.0  10.0
4     5  8.0  4.0   3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated this with a bit of setup for a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = [2,3,3,5,8,np.NAN,5,np.NAN,1]
s2 = [2,np.NAN,2,3,4,np.NAN,2,3,1]
s3 = [np.NAN,np.NAN,2,10,3,7,np.NAN,np.NAN,1]
data = {'time':np.arange(1,9+1),'s_1':s1,'s_2':s2,'s_3':s3}

df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

This will create a the DataFrame you posted above, but with an additional entry on the end so there will be two zones with continuous indexes.

I think the best approach from here is to drop all of the rows that are missing data and then count up the longest sequence in the remaining index. Something like this should do the trick:

```
sequence = np.array(df.dropna(how='any').index)    
longest_seq = max(np.split(sequence, np.where(np.diff(sequence) != 1)[0]+1), key=len)    
print(df.iloc[longest_seq])
```

Which will give you:

```
   time  s_1  s_2   s_3
2     3  3.0  2.0   2.0
3     4  5.0  3.0  10.0
4     5  8.0  4.0   3.0
```